# Keeping social share count after changing Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: social-sharing

I am going to change wordpress permalinks and will do 301 redirect from old to new URL's. But the problem is how can i keep my social sharing counts (like facebook,twitter, google +1) after the URL's are changed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to put the old link into the url attribute for each of the share buttons.

For example:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://domain.com/old-link" data-via="your_screen_name" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
```

[Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) also has an attribute called `counturl` which might be worth looking at. You'll have to do a bit of research on the others.